# Unable to open a chat in chatify Laravel

Tags: laravel, backend, pusher

I have created the chat module. It is also searching the username in database(users table) but when I click on the chat, nothing happens. I am attaching the snip of the console.

[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQsnE.png)
Any help would be apperciated.

Comment: In the snip of the console you see an internal server error message. Click on it. You'll end up at the Network tab with all kinds of red lines, just like in the Console tab. Click each line one by one, click on Response tab and screenshot it. Then ... go to your laravel.log. it will show the actual error. Copy/paste the stacktrace of the actual error

Comment: @UnderDog @UnderDog I got to the laravel log and tried to solve the issue. The error now is ```select count(*) as aggregate from (select `users`.*, MAX(ch_messages.created_at) max_created_at from `ch_messages` inner join `users` on `ch_messages`.`from_id` = `users`.`id` or `ch_messages`.`to_id` = `users`.`id` where (`ch_messages`.`from_id` = 4 or `ch_messages`.`to_id` = 4) and `users`.`id` != 4 group by `users`.`id`) as `aggregate_table`  ```

Comment: That's not an error, that's a SQL statement

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.